# python namespaces vs packages: making a package the default namespace

Tags: python, module, namespace-package

I have a project with an overarching namespace, with packages inside it. Here's the folder structure:

```
pypackage
├── pypackage             <-- Source code for use in this project.
|   |
│   ├── bin               <-- Module: Cli entry point into pyproject.
|   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   └── pypackage.py
|   |
|   └── core              <-- Module: Core functionality.
|       ├── __init__.py
|       └── pypackage.py
|
├── tests             
├── README.md         
└── setup.py
```

Pretty simple. If I want to import it I use:

```
from pypackage.core import pypackage
```

and it works great because my setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
...
NAME = 'pypackage'
setup(
    name=NAME,
    namespace_packages=[NAME],
    packages=[f'{NAME}.{p}' for p in find_packages(where=NAME)],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            f'{NAME} = {NAME}.bin.{NAME}:cli',
        ]
    },
    ...
)
```

However, I have legacy code that imports this `pypackage` when it used to just be a stand alone python file. like this:

```
import pypackage
```

So how do I make it so I can keep the same structure with namespaces and subpackages but still import it the old way? How do I turn this:

```
from pypackage.core import pypackage
```

into this:

```
import pypackage
```

In other words, **how do I alias the `pypackage.core.pypackage` module to be `pypackage` for when I'm importing `pypackage` into an external project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would add the 'old' names inside your new package by importing into the top-level package.

Names imported as globals in `pypackage/__init__.py` are attributes on the `pypackage` package. Make use of that to give access to 'legacy' locations:

```
# add all public names from pypackage.core.pypackage to the top level for
# legacy package use
from .core.pypackage import *
```

Now any code that uses `import pypackage` can use `pypackage.foo` and `pypackage.bar` if in reality these objects were defined in `pypackage.core.pypackage` instead.

Now, because `pypackage` is a [setuptools *namespace* package](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) you have a different problem; namespace packages are there for multiple separate distributions to install into so that top-level package must either be *empty* or only contain a minimum `__init__.py` file  (namespace packages created with empty directories require Python 3.3).

If you are the only publisher of distributions that use this namespace, you can cheat a little here and use a *single* `__init__.py` file in your `core` package that could use [pkg-util-style `__init__.py` file](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages) with the additional import I used above, but then you *must not use any `__init__.py` files in other distribution packages* or require that they all use the exact same `__init__.py` content. Coordination is key here.

Or you would have to use a different approach. Leave `pypackage` as a legacy wrapper module, and rename the new package format to use a new, different top-level name that can live next to the old module. At this point you can then just include the legacy package in your project, directly, as an extra top-level module.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Pieters has the right idea if I were using packages, but a namespace package is a setuptools thing.

So that didn't work. after more research, I learned that there's no way to do what I'm trying to do. So if I really want to do it I must convert everything to a regular package hierarchy instead of namespace package, then use martin's solution.

I've decided to modify the legacy code instead to import it the new way.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't immediately catch that you'd made `pypackage` a namespace package. I've updated my answer to reflect the options there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, this helps me understand much better