# Can objects be pulled into the top namespace level when using Python's implicit namespace support?

Tags: python, module, namespace-package

I have a project that I'd like to restructure to use Python's native implicit namespacing. I have code that I'd like to interface with like this:

```py
from mypackage import Foo
from mypackage.admin import Bar
```

The `admin` sub-package is in a completely separate repository. The files are organized like this:

```
mypackage
│
└─ core
   │  __init__.py
   │  file.py
   │  foo (contains class 'Foo')
   │  ...
```

And similarly the subpackage:

```
mypackage
│
└─ admin
   │  __init__.py
   │  bar.py (contains class Bar)
   │  another_folder
   │ ...
```

I had to place everything in my original package into a top level `core` subpackage to make the shared namespace work:

```py
from mypackage.core import Foo
from mypackage.admin import Bar
```

Is there a way I can structure this so I can access everything in my `core` package at the top level, as below?

```py
from mypackage import Foo
from mypackage.admin import Bar
```

I'm `import`-ing things as appropriate in the `__init__.py` files, but I don't know how to pull objects into the top-level namespace (if it's even supported).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486486/python-namespaces-vs-packages-making-a-package-the-default-namespace) which is nearly a duplicate, it turns out this isn't possible when using namespaces.